# Postgresql constraint : conditional check

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a table with 3 column : id1,id2,status
I want to have a constraint that match this example:

I can have only one `(val_X,val_Y,True)`
I can have many `(val_X,,val_Y,False)`

It must refuse a new row with same values `(val_x,val_y)` and true, and accept it with false.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:
create unique index on table_name (id1,id2, status)
where status = true;

I will have only one (val_x,val_y,True).